# K-Fold Cross-Validation - Formula for Standard Errors

Tags: cross-validation, standard-deviation, standard-error

I've recently tried to understand and formalize the one-standard-error rule for model selection by means of cross-validation. However, unfortunately I found most of the descriptions of the CV standard error, like on *Elements of Statistical Learning* for example, to be a bit vague. I also found [relevant slides](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/datamining/lectures/19-val2.pdf) which I'd like to have clarified. My understanding so far is as follows:

The k-fold cross-validation MSE of model $\hat{f}$ is
$$
CV_k (\hat{f}) = \dfrac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k MSE_i,
$$
where $MSE_i$ is the test MSE for the $i$th of $k$ folds, predicted by $\hat{f}$ fitted on all remaining folds.

Then the standard error is defined as
$$
SE(\hat{f}) = \dfrac{SD(\hat{f})}{\sqrt{k}}
$$
with standard deviation
$$
SD(\hat{f}) = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{k-1} \sum^k_{i=1}\bigl(MSE_i - CV_k (\hat{f})\bigr)^2}.
$$

Are these formulations correct? I especially wonder if variance, $\operatorname{var}\left(\mathrm{CV}_{1}(\theta), \ldots \mathrm{CV}_{K}(\theta)\right)$, on page 6 of the slides referenced is related to the distribution of all $k$ folds, like in my expression, or related to the all $n$ individual squared test errors. Also, is the degrees of freedom correction $k-1$ correct in this case?